# parse and display each node by way of foreach loop

Tags: php, parsing, foreach, simplexml

i am trying to parse usernames on a twitter rss feed using simplexml in php. there are a total of 16 names so i will like to use the foreach loop to run parse each one and return them. my only problem is the foreach loop.

```
$url = file_get_contents("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=basketball");
$source = simplexml_load_string($url);

foreach ($source as $match){
    $output = $match->name(0)->nodeValue = substr($match->name(0)->nodeValue, 0, strpos($match->name(0)->nodeValue, ' '));
    echo $output;
}
```

Comment: please paset ouput of `$source`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what error you're having. But, judging from the feed itself, it seems that `$match->name(0)->nodeValue` is incorrect; as `nodeValue` is not a method of the `SimpleXML` library, but rather the `Document Object Model` library.

You can replace all occurrences of `$match->name(0)->nodeValue` with `$match->author->name` as `->name` will output the node value for the tag `<name>`, which is a child of `<author>`.